# Cordova application for IOS device : How change submit button text on keyboard

Tags: html, ios, cordova, mobile

Actually I'm developing an ios application using Cordova, I want to change the submit button text in device keyboard to "**Send**" instead of "**Return**", I already succeeded to change the text to "**`Search`**" using the following html code

```
<form>
    <input type="search" name="search-query" id="search-query" />
</form>
```

Any one can help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

After about 4 years of "on and off" searching for a solution to this, I do not believe this is possible as the `UIWebView` will not allow you to set the keyboard submit text via JavaScript or an HTML attribute. So this would require the use of `<textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" returnKeyType="Send"/>` within a storyboard, or programatically through the view controller which doesn't solve the problem for cordova.

The [Ionic Keyboard Plugin for Cordova](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/54) have also not cracked this fairly popular request since the issue was opened Dec 2014.

Note: You can add `<button type="submit">Whatever</button>` below your textfield to at least allow the keyboard to display the blue "Go" button which submits the form.